# Backwards Chaining With Variables

Tags: prolog, logic, datalog

I have been reading up about inference in Prolog/Datalog and while forward chaining seems fairly simple to grasp, I have some issues with backward chaining with any sort of complex example which isn't simply propositional or used to determine a true or false value. I was reading an article the following example was given:

```
sg(X,X)
sg(X,Y) :- par(X, X1), par(Y,Y1), sg(X1,Y1)
```

Suppose we were to query `sg(a,W)` where `a` is a constant and `W` is a variable. This could be read as saying:

> Give me all those who are in the same generation as `a`.

The article firstly states that these particular rules will result in an infinite loop in Prolog/Datalog, but can be fixed by changing the second rule to:

```
sg(X,Y) :- par(X, X1),  sg(X1,Y1), par(Y,Y1).
```

Why would the original result in a loop? Secondly, what would the execution of this kind of query look like? When do values get bound to these variables?

Comment: in Datalog will not loop by sure. In Prolog, *you* should ensure the dependencies graph can be solved with a depth-first search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article seems not be very explicative. Assume the call is "sg(a,W)". Let analize first possibility:

```
sg(X,Y) :- par(X, X1), par(Y,Y1), sg(X1,Y1)
```

first "par" will be queried as "par(X=a,X1)", next as "par(Y=W,Y1)". This last query is a totally unbound query, and probably is what the article tries to skip.

Now, the second possibility:

```
 sg(X,Y) :- par(X, X1),  sg(X1,Y1), par(Y,Y1).
```

is executed as par(X=a,X1), sg(X1 /* bound in previous */, Y1), par(Y=W,Y1/* bound in previous */). As you can see, in all queries at least one of the arguments has been previously bound.

Comment: Why would X1 be bound in the second example but not the first?